# Find a font by specified characteristics in OSX

Tags: cocoa, fonts, core-text, fontmetrics

Is there any replacement for Windows's `CreateFont(..)` function in OSX?

I've tried to use `NSFontDescriptor` and its `matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:` method, but this method doesn't find the "closest" font, it finds the matched characteristics and also it can return `nil`.

Is there any way to find the closest font by specified characteristics (like a [CreateFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in OSX?

UPDATED

Something strange happens with NSFontDescriptor..

I have two pieces of code:

on Cocoa:

```
NSDictionary* fontTraits = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSFontSansSerifClass], NSFontSymbolicTrait,
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4], NSFontWidthTrait,
                            nil];

NSDictionary* fontAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    fontTraits, NSFontTraitsAttribute,
                    nil];

NSFontDescriptor* fontDescriptor = [NSFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:fontAttributes];

NSArray* matchedDescriptors = [fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:nil];
```

And using CoreText API:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef fontTraits = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

float weight = 0.4;

CFNumberRef fontWeight = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberFloat32Type, &weight);

CFDictionaryAddValue(fontTraits, kCTFontWeightTrait, fontWeight);

int symbolicTraits = kCTFontSansSerifClass;

CFNumberRef fontSymbolicTraits = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &symbolicTraits);

CFDictionaryAddValue(fontTraits, kCTFontSymbolicTrait, fontSymbolicTraits);

CFMutableDictionaryRef fontAttributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionaryAddValue(fontAttributes, kCTFontTraitsAttribute, fontTraits);

CTFontDescriptorRef fontDescriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes(fontAttributes);

CFArrayRef matchedDescriptors = CTFontDescriptorCreateMatchingFontDescriptors(fontDescriptor, 0);
```

I've created the same font descriptors in both cases, but in first case `matchedDescriptors` is `nil` and with CoreText API there are some fonts in `matchedDescriptors`. Is it a bug?

But in general, if I pass `nil` to `XXXMatchingFontDescriptorsXXX` as mandatory attribute, should it return at least one descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

I would please file a Radar if you haven't. I just got bit by this same difference in behavior myself.

A surprising thing while debugging, I found that `[fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorWithMandatoryKeys:]` is actually defined, though not documented, and functions as expected for a single descriptor that is. Meaning, it works just like `CTFontDescriptorCreateMatchingFontDescriptor()`.

While `[fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:]` definitely appears broken to me.

I found this problem when I was using `[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:size:]`, and it was matching things just fine, and as expected. Then I switched to `[fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:nil]`, and it returned nil for the same descriptor.

Something felt off, so I compared with CoreText APIs as you did, and came to the conclusion that I am sharing with you here.

I know you are looking at the list versions of these methods, I figured I would share that I went with this method in a `UIFontDescriptor` category:

```
- (nullable instancetype)my_matchingFontDescriptorWithMandatoryKeys:(nullable NSSet<UIFontDescriptorAttributeName> *)mandatoryKeys {
    return (__bridge_transfer UIFontDescriptor *)CTFontDescriptorCreateMatchingFontDescriptor((__bridge CTFontDescriptorRef)self, (__bridge CFSetRef)mandatoryKeys);
}
```